# AJAX + WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, wordpress

Делаю `ajax` запрос, который возвращает данные `Word Press`.

Но мне в результате ничего не возвращает.

PS: Пути правильны.

Код:

JS:

```
function ct (x) 
{ 
    $("div.backgroundin").empty() 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open('GET', '/wp-content/themes/bs/mods/category.php?ct='+x, true); 
    xhr.send(); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) return; 
        alert( xhr.responseText ); 
        $("div.backgroundin:empty").html(xhr.responseText); 
    } 
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    include('../../../../wp-load.php'); 
    $x = $_GET['ct']; 
    if ( have_posts() ) : 
        query_posts('cat=4'); 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?> 
<div class="card" id="card-s"> 
    <div class="card-img-top img-fluid"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(318,180)); ?></div> 
    <div class="card-body" id="card-body-s"> 
        <h4 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4> 
        <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Читать дальше</a> 
    </div> 
</div> 
<?php 
    endwhile; 
endif; 
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Comment: Это где вы такой Ajax с wp увидели? А где хуки? Начните читать отсюда https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: @KAGGDesign 
В чем плохая такая реализация?
Я просто не вижу смысла писать хуки или я не прав?

Помоги мне с верхним вариантом

Comment: В том, что она не работает.

Comment: @KAGGDesign то есть если загнать это все в хуки то все будет ок?)
Помоги исправить если он не рабочий

Comment: Как всякая большая система, WordPress имеет свои правила. Научитесь ими пользоваться для начала, а потом уж пишите свое. Пока что я вижу код, который совершенно совершенно невозможно поддерживать в команде.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Обьясни в чем именно ошибка ?

Comment: В том, что о нарушены все инструкции. Когда вместо бензобака топливо льют в двигатель, это заканчивается плохо, потому что инструкции не читали.

Comment: зачем вы после `if (have_posts())` меняете основной запрос командой `query_posts('cat=4');`?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, ajax в WP в общем случае прекрасно работает в обход admin-ajax и хуков. Если у топик стартера что-то не работает, то причина в чём-то другом

Comment: @alenkins конечно, работает. С чего бы ему не работать? Ajax - это взаимодействие php и js. Вопрос в другом. Представлен, эээ... код, который не имеет никакого значения для базы знаний под названием Stack Overflow. Потому что никому в здравом уме и трезвой памяти не придёт в голову написать нечто подобное. На фрилансе я бы заставил этот код работать, а здесь не вижу смысла.

Comment: @KAGGDesign разве ресурс не для того что б помогать пользователям 

Я не понимаю зачем писать комменты если ты все равно не будешь помогать

Comment: Нет, ресурс не для того. Я вам в первом комментарии подсказал, что делать. Вы упорно настаиваете на варианте "отладьте за меня мой код". Почитайте правила, это не приветствуется. Возьмите phpStorm + xdebug в руки и отлаживайте. Здесь база знаний, и имеют смысл только вопросы, которые помогут другим людям.

Comment: автор, ваш код у меня работает. Смотрите консоль браузера и логи сервера, вы косячите где-то вне того кода, который привели в пример (хотя и его не помешает отладить)

Comment: @alenkins уверен?
Сразу после подключения самого движка wp у меня в результате нету ответа

А если не подключать то методы не будут работать

Comment: `include`, кривые пути, еще и `query_posts` вишенкой..@СашаАдамов викинь этот опасный хлам и лучше спроси как правильно сделать то,что задумал.

Comment: @SeVlad нет пути ровные только что проверил

Если бы были кривыми то б в ответе был html код с ошибкой а не пустота

PS: Добавил echo прекрасно вывелся походу html код тоже в echo нужно

Comment: Ровные - это когда относительно корня/константы-функцииВП/етс и тп, а не гуляние по уровням относительно файла.